# Handling mutable shared objects in async/multithreading. Alternative to '.copy()'?

Tags: python, asynchronous, reference, shared-memory, python-multithreading

I'm writing a program that creates a bunch of workers to call an API asynchronously using `aiohttp`. However this question is about shared-objects. I assume I would run into the same or a similar issue if I was multithreading.

I have a set of default URL params which all the workers share, however two of these params' values are changed from worker to worker:

```
DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    'q' : None,                         #<==CHANGES per worker
    'offset' : '0',                     #<==CHANGES per worker
    'mkt' : 'en-US',                    #<==STATIC for all workers
    'moreParams' : '<most of the data>' #<==STATIC for all workers
}
```

Here's how I'm initializing my `Worker()` class:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        # this copy iexpensive when > 100 workers.
        self.initial_params = DEFAULT_PARAMS.copy()
        # but witout copying entire default params dict, the next line
        # would add alter the 'q' value for all instances of Worker.
        self.initial_params.update({'q' : q})
```

I'm looking for an alternative to calling `DEFAULT_PARAMS.copy()` for every new worker I create.

Figuring out how to pose this question has been a challenge. I suspect my answer may lie somewhere in class via instance attributes.

Here's an extremely barebones example of my program:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

DEFUALT_PARAMS = {
    'q' : None, #<==CHANGES per worker
    'offset' : '0', #<==CHANGES per worker
    'mkt' : 'en-US', #<==STATIC for all workers
    'moreParams' : '<most of the data>' #<==STATIC for all workers
}

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.initial_params = DEFUALT_PARAMS.copy() # <==expensive
        self.initial_params.update({'q' : q}) #<==without copying, overwrites ref for all classes.

    async def call_api(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sesh:
            async with sesh.get(
                'https://somesearchengine.com/search?',
                params=self.initial_params
            ) as resp:
                assert resp.status == 200
                print(await resp.json())


async def main(workers, *, loop=None):
    tasks = (asyncio.ensure_future(i.call_api(), loop=loop) for i in workers)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queries = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    workers = (Worker(i) for i in queries)
    loop.run_until_complete(main(workers, loop=loop))
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.copy`, that does exactly what you want, no?

Comment: Are you sure copying a dict is really a meaningful part of your runtime? I would expect your runtime to be dominated by network requests. Avoiding dict copies is likely to be useless effort.

Comment: I'm not certain. I'll check.

Comment: @user2357112 - my rationale was akin to this analogy: If I *have* to make 20k trips to a art dealership to buy 20k expensive pieces of art, sure that's going to dwarf my transportation costs, but if I care about costs I should still try to take 20k bus rides instead of 20k taxi rides...analogies aside, this is all moot though bc I didnt get specific enough with measuring resource usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying dictionaries, even for 100 workers, is *not that expensive*. You can create a copy of a 1000-key dictionary *and* update it, in 7 microseconds:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> from secrets import token_urlsafe
>>> test_dict = {token_urlsafe(): token_urlsafe() for _ in range(1000)}
>>> len(test_dict)
1000
>>> count, total = Timer("p = d.copy(); p.update({'q' : q})", "from __main__ import test_dict as d; q = 42").autorange()
>>> print(total/count*1000000)  # microseconds are 10**-6 seconds
7.146239580000611
```

So I'd say that there isn't really a problem here.

However, you are essentially *layering* dictionary contents; adjustments per worker to just one or two keys. Instead of creating a copy, you could use a [`collections.ChainMap()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to handle the layering. A `ChainMap()` object takes more than one dictionary and will look up keys in these until a value is found. No copy is created, and the top-most dictionary is used to set values when you mutate the map:

```
from collections import ChainMap

# ...
self.initial_params = ChainMap({'q': q}, DEFAULT_PARAMS)
```

Creating `ChainMap()` objects is cheaper still:

```
>>> count, total = Timer("p = ChainMap({'q': q}, d)", "from __main__ import test_dict as d; q = 42; from collections import ChainMap").autorange()
>>> print(total/count*1000000)
0.5310121239999717
```

so only half a microsecond. That comes at a price of slower iteration and per-key access, of course. It'll depend on how `aiohttp` processes these, I recommend you do your own micro-benchmarks with the `timeit` module to measure performance of actual operations that your code is executing.

But note that there is always a price to pay when trying to handle shared state like this, with any concurrency model, *and* sharing a dictionary between instances is always going to be problematic, even without concurrency.

Comment: While this is a thing that can be done, it has its own costs. It will slow down lookup for any key that has to be found in the DEFAULT_PARAMS. It may not actually pay off, and either way, it's probably going to vanish under the time taken by the network requests, anyway.

Comment: @user2357112: then you are stuck with copying up front. You have to pay this price *somewhere*.

Comment: @user2357112: I added some timings, the OP essentially *does not have a problem* here. Creating a shallow copy of a dictionary is highly optimised in Python.

Comment: Confirmed that I shouldn't have made assumptions about which part of my script is slow! I need to follow one of my import statements to find the culprit. This was really helpful regardless.

Answer (score -2):

If q is owned by the worker why not just make it an instance variable in the Worker itself.

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
      self.q = q
```

And wherever you want `q` do `self.q`